# Django CMS, Filer, and Cumulus for Cloud Files

Tags: django, upload, content-management-system, cloud, django-file-upload

I have django-cms set up with the cms plugin filer on a Rackspace cloud server. I have been reading and searching around and found cumulus. Is there a way to make all three work together in a way that I can use filer from the cms to upload via cumulus to Rackspace's Cloud Files service? Or is there a better method/module? I would really like to keep using django-cms as I like its interface and have already produced pages with it.

**Clarification:** How do I set up django-filer to use django-cumulus? I have tried adding `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage'` to my settings, but this just results in me not being able to add any cms plugins at all in the page editing in admin (not even Text).

Comment: Have you tried django-cumulus? what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` to `'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage'`? The `STATICFILES_STORAGE` is only used in combination with `manage.py collectstatic` (and the `django.contrib.staticfiles` system in general), not uploaded files (such as used in `django-filer` and `cmsplugin-filer`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that is the line I had meant to copy/paste. I have DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage' in my settings. When I edit a cms page, add an image plugin, choose and upload an image, filer dialog just shows undefined. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/e11gi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to drop filer and just use the built-in file and image plugins provided by django-cms. They work just fine together.